# performActionForShortcutItem in Xcode 8 beta 6

Tags: swift, xcode, uiapplicationshortcutitem

Since I updated to Xcode 8 beta 6 I get a warning for:

`application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void)`

"Instance method `application(_:performActionFor:completionHandler:)` nearly matches optional requirement `application(_:performActionFor:completionHandler:)` of protocol UIApplicationDelegate"

But the method I have in my code is the one that autocomplete fills in. Apparently the method has been changed because my shortcut items don't work anymore but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Command-click on `UIApplicationDelegate`, and you can find this:

(Or see [the latests documentation of `UIApplicationDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622935-application).)

```
optional public func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem,
    completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Swift.Void)
```

Try changing your method header to:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem,
    completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
```